# Post-hoc test for PERMANOVA (adonis2) of a single variable (vegan package)

Tags: anova, nonparametric, post-hoc, two-way, vegan

I have a 2x2 study design to test for the interaction between two drugs (i.e. with or without drug1 and/or drug2), with a single continuous outcome for each combination. The data are unbalanced and non-parametric, and it seems the best solution for a non-parametric alternative to a classic 2-way ANOVA is the PERMANOVA (vegan package).

This seems to work very well...

```
library(vegan)
adonis2(outcome ~ drug1 * drug2, data=df)
```

Following this, I would like to perform a post-hoc test (e.g. Tukey, Bonferroni) to test the effect size between specific combinations of treatment.

I understand the package pairwiseAdonis can deal with this, but this does not work for me as it assumes that multiple variables are being measured: I have only a single continuous outcome to measure.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: adonis is for analysis of distance matrices - the response must be a community data matrix or a dissimilarity matrix. Can you provide more detail about why you think your data is unsuitable for standard anova? I suspect a generalized linear model would be much more appropriate than adonis.